# Histograma en Matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un dataframe de pandas con 2 columnas, en una hay valores del 0 al 2 y en la otra una hora del día, desde las 01:00 a las 24:00. Me interesa reflejar cuantas veces aparece el 0 en cada hora del día, cuantas veces aparece el 1 y cuantas veces aparece el 2. A simple vista me parece sencillo pero no lo consigo. He pensado en un gráfico de barras o un histograma. Sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITADA**

He solventado el error que menciono en los comentarios pero he obtenido el gráfico y se repiten algunas horas en el eje X, muestro ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITADA 2 - AÑADO MI CODIGO**

```
import pandas as pd

#Carga el dataframe usado para los graficos
file = pd.read_excel('Datos.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df['hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hora'], errors='coerce')
df.set_index('hora', inplace=True)

df["0"] = df.valor == 0
df["1"] = df.valor == 1
df["2"] = df.valor == 2

result = df.resample("H").sum()

ax = result[["0", "1", "2"]].plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16, 4))
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"), result.index))
```

Adjunto el archivo .xlsx que uso también. Mi principal problema, como ya comentaba en uno de los comentarios, es que quiero que se agrupen todo lo que ocurra a las 22:00 por ejemplo, en la misma columna, sin importar el día, mes o año. Gracias por la ayuda, un saludo.

DATOS: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-_W6ueoqhRT6xAGFDa57iltw4WkPWAyL

**EDITADA 3 - NUEVO PROBLEMA**

Tengo el dataframe pero antes de generar los graficos quiero filtrarlo, por ejemplo si hubiera otra columna con IDs, quiero hacer:

```
df_filtered = df[df['id'] == '123456789']
```

Esto me genera un Dataframe llamado df_filtered con el que luego hacer los gráficos. En la teoría es simple, pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

Y no consigo solucionarlo, alguna idea?

Comment: Creo que para entender claramente qué pasa es necesario que muestres tu código, y posiblemente también los datos. Sospecho que la columna de "horas" se extiende durante varios días. En ese caso ¿quieres agrupar los datos que hayan tenido lugar la misma hora aunque sea en diferentes días?

Comment: Si, es justo lo que quiero, sin tener en cuenta el día, que lo agrupe todos únicamente por horas.

Comment: Voy a intentar limpiar mi código y mis datos, no lo he subido por temas de confidencialidad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El truco es que el índice del dataframe sea la hora (y sea de tipo `datetime`), para poder hacer un *resample* por el intervalo deseado, en tu caso por horas.

El resample es una especie de `groupby()`, en el sentido de que el resultado son una serie de grupos. Cada grupo contiene todos los datos dentro de una hora. Luego puedes agregar esos grupos para contar cuántos hay con cada valor.

Se me ocurren dos formas de hacerlo. Una fácil de entender, pero poco flexible. Otra mucho más automatizada, pero más difícil de entender. Te muestro ambas.

### Datos de entrada

Parto de un dataframe como el siguiente:

```
                     valor
hora                      
2019-01-01 00:06:00      1
2019-01-01 00:15:00      2
2019-01-01 00:25:00      2
2019-01-01 00:30:00      0
2019-01-01 00:36:00      0
2019-01-01 00:43:00      2
2019-01-01 00:53:00      2
2019-01-01 00:59:00      0
...
```

El cual he generado con el siguiente código, por si quieres replicar el experimento:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random


def generar_hora_y_valor(hora_inicio=None):
  if hora_inicio is None:
    hora_inicio = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
  hora = hora_inicio
  hora_fin = hora_inicio + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
  while True:
    hora += datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*random.randint(1,10))
    if hora > hora_fin:
      break
    yield {"hora": hora, "valor": random.randint(0,2) }

df = pd.DataFrame(generar_hora_y_valor()).set_index("hora")
```

Básicamente comienzo a medianoche y voy sumando incrementos al azar entre 1 y 10 minutos hasta llegar a la siguiente medianoche. Esos *timestamps* los guardo en una columna llamada "horas". Así algunas horas tendrán más datos que otras. Para cada uno de esos *timestamps* genero un número al azar entre 0 y 2, que guardo en la columna "valor"

En el dataframe final uso la columna "horas" como índice y por tanto desaparece, quedando solo la columna "valor".

### Método sencillo

Añado al dataframe tres columnas booleanas que dicen si en cada *timestamp* el valor fue 0, 1 ó 2:

```
df["0"] = df.valor == 0
df["1"] = df.valor == 1
df["2"] = df.valor == 2
```

El dataframe resultante es:

```
                     valor      0      1      2
hora                                           
2019-01-01 00:06:00      1  False   True  False
2019-01-01 00:15:00      2  False  False   True
2019-01-01 00:25:00      2  False  False   True
2019-01-01 00:30:00      0   True  False  False
2019-01-01 00:36:00      0   True  False  False
2019-01-01 00:43:00      2  False  False   True
2019-01-01 00:53:00      2  False  False   True
2019-01-01 00:59:00      0   True  False  False
2019-01-01 01:08:00      2  False  False   True
2019-01-01 01:09:00      2  False  False   True
...
```

Ahora basta resamplear y usar `.sum()` como agregador. Ya que `True` equivale a 1 y `False` a 0, esto te dará el recuento deseado:

```
result = df.resample("H").sum()

                     valor    0    1    2
hora                                     
2019-01-01 00:00:00      9  3.0  1.0  4.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00     17  2.0  1.0  8.0
2019-01-01 02:00:00      8  8.0  2.0  3.0
2019-01-01 03:00:00     12  6.0  2.0  5.0
2019-01-01 04:00:00     11  3.0  5.0  3.0
...
```

Puedes pintarlo como histograma así:

```
result[["0", "1", "2"]].plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16, 4))
```

[image: resultado]

### Método complejo

El método anterior tiene el inconveniente de que tenemos que saber de antemano los posibles valores que pueden aparecer, y crear columnas para cada uno. El siguiente método es más automático.

Operamos directamente sobre el `df` original que sólo tiene una columna `"valor"`, y lo resampleamos por horas. A cada grupo le aplicamos una función que usa `collections.Counter()` para contar los valores que aparecen en ella. El resultado de cada una de estas cuentas es un diccionario:

```
import collections
resultado = df.resample("H").aggregate(lambda x: collections.Counter(x.valor))
```

Este es el aspecto del dataframe `resultado`:

```
hora
2019-01-01 00:00:00    {1: 1, 2: 4, 0: 3}
2019-01-01 01:00:00    {2: 8, 0: 2, 1: 1}
2019-01-01 02:00:00    {0: 8, 2: 3, 1: 2}
2019-01-01 03:00:00    {0: 6, 2: 5, 1: 2}
2019-01-01 04:00:00    {1: 5, 2: 3, 0: 3}
...
```

Para convertir los diccionarios que tenemos en cada celda de nuevo en columnas, podemos hacer:

```
resultado.apply(pd.Series)
```

```
                       0    1    2
hora                              
2019-01-01 00:00:00  3.0  1.0  4.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00  2.0  1.0  8.0
2019-01-01 02:00:00  8.0  2.0  3.0
2019-01-01 03:00:00  6.0  2.0  5.0
2019-01-01 04:00:00  3.0  5.0  3.0
2019-01-01 05:00:00  2.0  4.0  4.0
...
```

Por tanto podemos hacer la gráfica así:

```
resultado.apply(pd.Series).plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
```

Y sale lo mismo que por el otro método:

[image: Segundo resultado]

### Actualización: un método más

Se me ha ocurrido otra forma similar a la del último método, pero usando funcionalidad Pandas (`pd.Series.value_counts`) en lugar de `collections.Count()`.

Aquí tienes este enfoque en una línea y sin más explicaciones. Saca la misma gráfica que los dos anteriores:

```
result = df.valor.resample("H").aggregate(pd.value_counts).unstack()
result.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
```

### Bonus: formato del eje X

Aunque esto no estaba en la pregunta, si te molesta que el eje X muestre la fecha cuando solo quieres la hora, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ax = result.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"), result.index))
```

y obtienes:

[image: Resultado solo horas en eje X]

## Actualización: Usando los datos reales del usuario

El usuario actualiza su pregunta y suministra un enlace a una excel con sus datos reales. En esa hoja puede observarse que las filas no están ordenadas cronológicamente:

```
print(pd.read_excel("Datos.xlsx").head())
```

```html
                 hora  valor
0 2017-06-03 10:37:12      0
1 2017-06-05 08:03:28      1
2 2017-06-03 23:17:33      1
3 2017-06-05 10:15:36      1
4 2017-06-03 05:33:45      2
```

Puede verse cómo se alternan datos del día 5 y del día 3. Eso explica por qué en el eje X de la gráfica del usuario las horas también salen "desordenadas". Lo primero por tanto será ordenar correctamente el dataframe una vez leido y una vez establecida la hora como índice. Basta hacer:

```
df = df.sort_index()
```

Tras agrupar por horas como expliqué más arriba, el resultado presenta este aspecto:

```html
                            0     1     2
    hora                                 
    2017-06-03 01:00:00   1.0   1.0   1.0
    2017-06-03 05:00:00   NaN   2.0   3.0
    2017-06-03 10:00:00   2.0   1.0   2.0
    2017-06-03 22:00:00   NaN   NaN   1.0
    2017-06-03 23:00:00  11.0  10.0  11.0
```

Donde lo siguiente que observamos es que hay muchas horas para las cuales no existen datos (por ejemplo, se salta de la 1:00 a las 5:00). En mi opinión esas horas deberían aparecer también en la gráfica, sólo que con valor 0. Por tanto tenemos que rellenar las horas que faltan.

Para eso generamos un rango de fechas completo espaciado por horas y reindexamos el resultado según ese rango:

```
rango_fechas = pd.date_range(start=result.index[0], end=result.index[-1], freq="1H")
result = result.reindex(rango_fechas)
result.index.name = "hora"  # Hay que ponerle nombre que se perdió al reindexar
```

Ahora el dataframe tiene ya todas las horas, y ha rellenado con `NaN` las filas para las que no había datos:

```html
                       0    1    2
hora                              
2017-06-03 01:00:00  1.0  1.0  1.0
2017-06-03 02:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 03:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 04:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 05:00:00  NaN  2.0  3.0
```

Si pintamos ahora el resultado:

```
ax = result[[0,1,2]].plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16, 4))
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"), result.index))
```

[image: Imagen]

Vemos que las horas aparecen correctamente ordenadas y no falta ninguna. Pero vemos que se repiten porque los datos abarcan varios días.

Sólo queda por tanto agrupar todos los datos que pertenezcan a una misma hora para sumarlos. Esto podemos hacerlo con `groupby()` en la forma siguiente:

```
final = result.groupby(result.index.hour).sum()
final.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
```

y así obtener la gráfica:

[image: Final]

Observa que el eje X muestra la hora en la forma `0`, `1`, etc. y no como `00:00`, `01:00`, etc. Ello se debe a que al hacer el `groupby(result.index.hour)` estamos agrupando por el *valor* de la hora, que es un entero. El dataframe resultante de esa agrupación ya no tiene objetos `datetime` en su índice, sino enteros, el valor de cada hora.

Si quieres que la gráfica muestre las horas en un formato más "horario", podemos hacer trampa re-etiquetando el eje X así (no podemos usar `strftime()` como antes porque como ya he dicho el índice ya no es de tipo datetime):

```
ax = final.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
ax.set_xticklabels(map(lambda x: "%02d:00" % x, final.index))
```

Y el resultado final es este:

[image: Resultado final]

### Actualizción 3: Respuesta a edición 3

En la última consulta, el dataframe tiene una columna `id` por la que se quiere filtrar. El filtrado sería trivial, como el propio usuario sugiere:

```
df_filtered = df[df['id'] == '1234567']
```

El problema es que como consecuencia del filtrado el resultado tendrá muchos menos datos y es problable que uno de los valores no aparezca ninguna vez, lo que puede "confundir" a `pd.value_counts`. En un experimento que he hecho, tras un filtrado la tabla se quedó recortada a lo siguiente:

```
hora
2017-06-03 01:12:06    1
2017-06-03 05:33:45    2
2017-06-03 23:05:09    2
2017-06-03 23:17:33    1
Name: valor, dtype: int64
```

en la que vemos que no aparece ninguna vez el 0. Por alguna razón que desconozco, al hacer sobre ese dataframe la siguiente operación `pd.value_counts` como proponía en una de mis soluciones:

```
result = df_filtered.valor.resample("H").aggregate(pd.value_counts)
```

ya no sale el mismo formato que salía cuando había más datos, sino uno muy raro en el que aparecen todas las horas, incluso las que no contienen valores, y a cada hora asignada una lista (la mayoría de las veces vacía) o un número que indica cuántas veces se repite un valor, pero sin especificar de qué valor se trata. Estas son las primeras filas de este resultado:

```
hora
2017-06-03 01:00:00         1
2017-06-03 02:00:00        []
2017-06-03 03:00:00        []
2017-06-03 04:00:00        []
2017-06-03 05:00:00         1
2017-06-03 06:00:00        []
2017-06-03 07:00:00        []
```

Además de que se ha perdido información (hay una repetición de un valor a la 1:00:00, pero ¿de qué valor?), sobre se resultado no se puede aplicar ya `.unstack()` como hacía en mi solución anterior (intentarlo produce el error que el usuario ha reportado).

Sin embargo el método de usar `collections.Counter()` sigue funcionando:

```
import collections

result = (df_filtered.valor.resample("H")
          .aggregate(lambda x: collections.Counter(x))
          .apply(pd.Series))
```

El resultado es el adecuado para continuar con el resto del procesamiento:

```
                       1    2
hora                         
2017-06-03 01:00:00  1.0  NaN
2017-06-03 02:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 03:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 04:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 05:00:00  NaN  1.0
2017-06-03 06:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 07:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 08:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 09:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 10:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 11:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 12:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 13:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 14:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 15:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 16:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 17:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 18:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 19:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 20:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 21:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 22:00:00  NaN  NaN
2017-06-03 23:00:00  1.0  1.0
```

A partir de este dataframe, se seguiría como en el final de mi respuesta anterior:

```
final = result.groupby(result.index.hour).sum()
final.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(16,4))
```

[image: Final]

Comment: Muchas gracias Abulafia, he intentado adaptar el código para mi programa y me lanza el siguiente mensaje de error:

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: Pues tendrás que poner el código que genera tú dataframe

Comment: Mi dataframe lo cargo a partir de un archivo .excel o .csv en el que tengo los datos en el mismo formato que has mostrado tu. Es decir la fecha esta en formato "2010-03-03 10:23:23". Parece que se queja que la columna no es del tipo DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex. He probado tambien a usar la funcion que proporciona PANDAS pd.to_datetime() para convertir la columna de fechas de String a Datetime pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: @AlfredoLopezRodes He actualizado la respuesta para mostrar cómo trabajar con tus datos, que presentaban varios problemas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda Abulafia.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta con un nuevo problema que me ha surgido.

Comment: Mira la Actualización 3 de mi respuesta, @AlfredoLopezRodes

Comment: Gracias @Abulafia, ha funcionado.